# Detecting a user accessing our website with accessibility features

Tags: html, accessibility

We have implemented the responsive website with accessibility features. It's built in Angular 1.x. I would like to know whether the user is accessing the site through accessibility feature or not. How do I access device parameters in the javascript?

Answer (score 2):

People using screenreaders use standard browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer/Edge, ...). They gives the screenreaders the information on the structure of the page through the accessibility API. But it's impossible to know whether or not the user uses the accessibility API.

Of course, you can track simple things like whether or not the user use a mouse by tracking the `onmousemove` event, or whether or not the user use the keyboard (through `onkeyup` event for instance). A screenreader will emulate certain actions like `focus()`, `click()` but not all the standard keyboard/mouse events. And you'll have to consider also touch events.

Comment: *_currently_ impossible. Standards evolve.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides Nope. It's an API. The browser provides it. They may use it or not. If you share a braille display with your wife, and you're using the same computer, you can't know if the user is currently using the accessibility API or not.

Comment: But is it naïve to imagine a future where the assistive device is cooperating with the browser to send a header, like, I dunno, theoretically, `X-Assistive-Device-Parameters`, which a remote web site can inspect and operate on?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extremely different realities among assistive technology users: various software and/or hardware, for various kinds of disabilities.
Thus your question is vague: do you want to detect screen readers ? screen magnifiers ? pointing devices for people who can't use their hands (driven with the voice and/or their eyes) ? reading helps for dys problems ? something else ?
As you can see, the universe of assistive technlologies is very wide, and there are often as many ways to customize them as there are users.

However, regardless of what you are trying to detect anyway, the answer will more or less be always basicly the same: there is no 100% proof solution, at most solutions which work in some particular cases only.
For example, if you make a search on stackoverflow or anywhere else on how to detect if the user has or hasn't a keyboard, a mouse, a touch screen, etc. you will see that there are a lof of different answers, but none of them are really 100% exact nor perfect in all cases.
You might get more or less obvious clues that he has or hasn't this or that, but you will never be 100% sure; and sometimes, you get a part of certainty only after a while.

For detecting screen readers or magnifiers, that's one step harder in terms of difficulty. What's a typical scren reader user ? keyboard, no mouse and no touch ? Perhaps not. What if I have enough sight to distinguish main zones, but not enough to be able to click precisely on a button having a small icon ?
What if I'm using a dictation software and can't use the keyboard for some reason, or just because right now my hands are busy  ?
On iOS there exist VoiceOver, so a screen reader may have a touch screen. And so forth.

And there is another problem with detection: I have a mouse, but it doesn't implies that I will necessarily use it. What about computers that can be switched between a laptop mode and a tablet mode ?
IN the opposite, I can be a screen reader user and may move the mouse a bit by misstake. 
Your site will just make wrong conclusions about what I am, and will present me with an unappropriate interface.

Ah, and another final one: what if I'm blind, try to use your site, don't manage to do it, and finally call a sighted person to help me ? The person won't be able to help me because your site took the screen reader interface ?

Here is the truth: don't assume anything about what the user has or hasn't / who he is or isn't. 
Think that the user may use all input means at the same time or that he may change them at any time.

D'ont be faoul: give alternative texts and make your components accessible all the time, not only when you know that the user is using a screen reader.

Design your thing in such a way that you don't need device detection as most as you can.

Comment: Asking for feature detection for screen readers and other assistive devices is a good instinct, though. Yes, it's a complicated issue. However, I think the OP has a valid, if initially poorly worded question, and the simple answer is "no, there is no simple way to programmatically detect that."

Comment: I think the feature detection is the way to go but instead of trying to detect accessibility users, try to detect users that move mouse normally, use default font size for `<html>` element etc. That is, default to fully accessible content for everything (including focus indicators etc) and selectively make the content less jarring to visual users if heuristics or feature detect suggests that they do not need help. However, if you feature detect e.g. the default font size, do not assume that the user can use mouse – default font size probably just means that user is okay with usually sized text